# How to run linear regression of a masked array

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to run a linear regression on two masked arrays. Unfortunately, linear regression ignores the masks and regresses all variables. My data has some `-9999` values where values where our instrument did not measure any data. These -9999 values produce a line that does not fit the data at all.

My code is this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array( [ 2.019, 1.908, 1.902, 1.924, 1.891, 1.882, 1.873, 1.875, 1.904,
            1.886, 1.891, 2.0, 1.902, 1.947,2.0280, 1.95, 2.342, 2.029,
            2.086, 2.132, 2.365, 2.169, 2.121, 2.192,2.23, -9999, -9999, -9999, -9999,
            1.888, 1.882, 2.367 ] ).reshape((-1,1))
 
y = np.array( [ 0.221, 0.377, 0.367, 0.375, 0.258, 0.16 , 0.2  , 0.811,
          0.330, 0.407, 0.421, -9999, 0.605, 0.509, 1.126, 0.821,
          0.759, 0.812, 0.686, 0.666, 1.035, 0.436, 0.753, 0.611,
          0.657, 0.335, 0.231, 0.185, 0.219, 0.268, 0.332, 0.729 ] )

    
model = LinearRegression().fit(x, y )

r_sq = model.score( x, y )

print( 'coefficient of determination:', r_sq)
print( 'intercept:', model.intercept_)
print( 'slope:', model.coef_)

x_line = np.linspace (x.min(), x.max(), 11000)
y_line = (model.coef_* x_line) + model.intercept_
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots( figsize = ( 10, 10) )
plt.scatter( x, y )
plt.plot( x_line, y_line )
plt.show()
```

Which gives us
[this scatter plot with the regression plotted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjb2v.png). Note: most of the values are in the upper right hand corner...they're too close together to differentiate.

Is there a way to run the regression while ignoring the masked `-9999` values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can just remove the offending values

```py
invalid = -9999
valid_indices = (x[:, 0] != invalid) & (y != invalid)
xv = x[valid_indices].reshape(-1, 1)
yv = y[valid_indices]

# The rest of your code, using `xv` and `yv` instead of `x` and `y`.
```

You should see a plot like the below, with a pretty reasonable line of best fit.

[image]

Comment: That works great! Is there a way I can replace the -9999 values instead of just removing them?

Comment: @danrod13 Not without introducing a selection bias. What would you replace them with? Let's say you replaced missing data with the "local median". Well, _how_ local? That also introduces an assumption that your data is "smooth" in some way. But _how_ smooth? So you _could_ pick something, but you just need to be crystal clear on how that changes the regression in a possibly biased and undesirable way.

Comment: Your way definitely makes sense for replacing -9999 values. In some of the variables there are -8888 and -7777 values which are data below and above the level of detection, respectively. The standard procedure is to replace those error values with half of the LOD instead of removing them outright.

Comment: You mean values that saturate whatever sensor you're using, or fall below the noise floor? I would be very careful about postulating any particular value for those samples, unless you have a pretty good a priori model for the distribution of your data. By definition you know _nothing_ about those values, except the minimal/maximal value, without some other knowledge the distribution.